# Push values into hidden field array using Jquery in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want that when user click on any row of table base div.I insert id of that row into hidden

field array. Hence user can select multiple rows.And i want insert id into hidden field array

when click event will be invoke..

My html code is

```
     <div id="originator_rates">
       <% unless @orig_codes.blank? %>
         <% @orig_codes.each do |code| %>
         <div id="<%= code.id %>_"  onclick="rate_entry_select_originator('<%=code.id%>')" class="rate_select">
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'code_id[]', :id => 'code_id' %>              
         </div>  
      <%end%> 
      <div>
```

my js code is

```
       function rate_entry_select_originator(code_id) {
          $('#code_id').push(code_id);  //how i push values into array


       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make hidden_field array.rather than you use single hidden field and push values in it comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the list of code id then instead of managing multiple hidden fields manage single one (id as CSV value) .

Try and made below changes:

Change into the passing value of javascript function

```
<div id="<%= code.id %>_" onclick="rate_entry_select_originator(this)" class="rate_select">
```

Add before start of the loop.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'code_ids', :id => 'code_ids' %>
```

Modify your javascript function :

```
    function rate_entry_select_originator(code_id) {
      var code_id_val = $('#code_ids').val();
      var code_id_arr = code_id_val.split(',');
      var code_id = $(this).attr('id');

      if($(this).hasClass("color_class"))
      {
        $(this).addClass("color_class");
        $('#code_ids').val(code_id_val+','+code_id);
      }
      else
      {
        $(this).removeClass("color_class");
        // To remove element from aaray
        code_id_arr = jQuery.grep(code_id_arr, function(code_id) {
          return value != removeItem;
        });
        $('#code_ids').val(code_id_arr.join(','));

      }
    }

Please correct some errors , I didn't run it.
Hope that will help.
```